# BIRT report custom font not shown

Tags: birt

My birt-eclipse 4.6.0 editor displays custom fonts correctly.
I'm trying to understand why some custom fonts are displayed while other are not (falling back to standard) when report is generated to PDF (or other format) on birt runtime 4.4.2 server.

I'm registering custom fonts using below method when server starts:

```
com.lowagie.text.FontFactory.register("/font/path")
```

Same problem happens when I click **Run -> View Report -> As PDF** in eclipse-editor.
For example **AvenirNextLTPro-MediumCn.otf** is displayed, but **AvenirLTStd-Medium.otf** is not. Same happens with *.ttf fonts - some displayed correctly, others do not. But all are visible in birt-eclipse editor.

Editor and runtime server are running on same machine - Ubuntu 16.04, fonts are copied to **/usr/share/fonts** and registered with **fc-cache -fv** command.

Why some fonts are not visible in PDF?

Answer (score 0):

Could not find exact cause of the problem, I think it is somehow related to font naming.
Solution that worked for me:

```
com.lowagie.text.FontFactory.register(String path, String alias)
```

There is a "register" method that accepts second parameter - font alias.  In my case, second parameter was "Avenir LT Std". Took this title from BIRT-eclipse editor's font drop-down list.